# unable to use AddObject method to insert data into the Database using Entity framework version 5.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am unable to use AddObject method to insert data into the Database using Entity framework version 5.0. please help me through.

```
    List<Error> errorlist = new List<Error>();
    errorlist.Add(new Error{ Authentication="From", dateTime=DateTime.Now.ToString(), messageText="xyz", server="10.11.12.217", Username="John"});
     errorlist.Add(new Error{ Authentication="From", dateTime=DateTime.Now.ToString(), messageText="xyz", server="10.11.12.217", Username="George"});
     using (TransactionScope transe = new TransactionScope())
     {
         using (SportsEntities bulk = new SportsEntities())
         {
             ErrorLog error = new ErrorLog();
             for (int i = 0; i < errorlist.Count; i++)
             {
                 error.AUTHENTICATION_MODE = errorlist[i].Authentication;
                 error.DATE_ARRIVAL = errorlist[i].dateTime;
                 error.MESSAGE = errorlist[i].messageText;
                 error.SERVER_DETAILS = errorlist[i].server;
                 error.USERNAME = errorlist[i].Username;
                 bulk.ErrorLogs.AddObject(error);
             }
             bulk.SaveChanges();
         }
         transe.Complete();
     }
}
```

Comment: Try `bulk.ErrorLogs.Add(error);`  (just `.Add()` - not `.AddObject()`) .....

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Add() instead of this .AddObject().
But if you still want to use it :

Double click your .edmx file , press F4 or right click and go to properties .There you will see "Code Generation Strategy" : T4 .Change this to "Legacy object Context". This will Create necessary files in designer.cs. Now delete your tt files and Context.tt created by T4 generation strategy . You will be able to use .AddObject().

.AddObject() is property of Object Context. Where .Add() is of DbContext.